# Symfony form with nested tree - exception: Maximum function nesting level of "512" reached

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I need to work with lists of categories with unlimited nesting.

I get the following exception:

> Maximum function nesting level of "512" reached, aborting! (500 Internal Server Error)

I found an option with hack, but maybe there is something better?
[Nested form in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932271/nested-form-in-symfony#answer-47948867)

full example: https://github.com/Gemorroj/symfony-form-tree

The main code is causing the problem:

```php
class TreeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => self::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Tree::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What result do you want to achieve? What king of form field? Dropdown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony | Forms | Self-referencing CollectionType field - ERROR: out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767726/symfony-forms-self-referencing-collectiontype-field-error-out-of-memory)

Comment: yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767726/symfony-forms-self-referencing-collectiontype-field-error-out-of-memory it looks just like mine. but I could not solve the problem with the help of events. I get a new error about incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is triggered by XDebug in your development environment.

Increase the value of the `xdebug.max_nesting_level` setting inside your `php.ini` to resolve your issue:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 2048
```

From the [Documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/basic#max_nesting_level):

> **xdebug.max_nesting_level**
>
> The value of this setting is the maximum level of nested functions that are allowed before the script will be aborted.
>
> Type: integer, Default value: 256
>
> Before Xdebug 2.3, the default value was 100.

Comment: No, it's no xdebug problem. 


It is an infinite recursive creation of objects. 


Whatever limit I set, it will all be used up. 

If I remove xdebug, it will stop due to RAM consumption.